# How can I upload a picture to my django app on heroku and get it to be displayed?

Tags: python, django, database, heroku, web-applications

I have a django application on heroku where some data is added in the admin settings. It is linked to my github. One of the things you add is a picture. It doesn't show up on the site after its uploaded. What could be the cause and solution?

Comment: If your database is getting destroyed when you deploy, that can only be because you are using sqlite, which you **must not do** on Heroku.

Answer (score 0):

I've been running my django app in heroku for about 6 months now and I've never experienced `db gets reset` when ever I updated/deploy/push to heroku
**note** I'm using heroku postgress for db